# pytest with inmemory mysql setup for tests - can't get fixtures to work

Tags: pytest

new to pytest.

I am trying to create a test class with several tests in it.
Now, I want this test to:

1. create in memory mysql and schema with tables (only once)
2. truncate tables (after each test)
3. dispose in memory mysql

After some research I came across [pytest-mysql](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mysql/) but I just cannot make it work with the fixtures.

I tried some different test settings:

- In the following case The mysql param is a bound method returning None if invoke it.

  ```
    from pytest_mysql import factories

    mysql_process = factories.mysql_proc(port=8888, logs_prefix='/tmp')         
    mysql = factories.mysql('mysql_my_proc')



   class BaseTest(object):

      @pytest.mark.usefixtures('mysql')
      def setup_method(self, mysql):
          self._setup_mysql(mysql)
  ```
- In this case I didn't get anythin in the mysql param at all.

  ```
     from pytest_mysql import factories

     mysql_process = factories.mysql_proc(port=8888, logs_prefix='/tmp')         
     mysql = factories.mysql('mysql_my_proc')



    class BaseTest(object):

       def setup_method(self, mysql):
           self._setup_mysql(mysql)
  ```
- In this case I had errors of scoping (found it here on stack overflow):

  ```
     from pytest_mysql import factories

     mysql_process = factories.mysql_proc(port=8888, logs_prefix='/tmp')         
     mysql = factories.mysql('mysql_my_proc')


    class BaseTest(object):

       @classmethod
       @pytest.fixture(scope="class", autouse=True)
       def setup(self):
           self._setup_mysql(mysql)
  ```

I haven't even started to think about truncate and teardown phases.. yet.

Can anybodey help me here?